# Laravel Cart and controller

Tags: database, laravel, migration

I am having issue with the route and controller.

The error code consist of sql column not found which is looking for column id from items table. Which im quite curious due to the differences with my migration.

CartController.php

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use App\Cart;
 use App\CartItem;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CartController extends Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function addItem ($itemNo){

    $cart = Cart::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first();

    if(!$cart){
        $cart =  new Cart();
        $cart->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
        $cart->save();
    }

    $cartItem  = new Cartitem();
    $cartItem->itemNo=$itemNo;
    $cartItem->cart_id= $cart->id;
    $cartItem->save();

    return redirect('/cart');

}

public function showCart(){
    $cart = Cart::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->first();

    if(!$cart){
        $cart =  new Cart();
        $cart->user_id=Auth::user()->id;
        $cart->save();
    }

    $items = $cart->cartItems;
    $total=0;
    foreach($items as $item){
        $total+=$item->product->price;
    }

    return view('cart.view',['items'=>$items,'total'=>$total]);
}

public function removeItem($id){

    CartItem::destroy($id);
    return redirect('/cart');
}
```

}

ItemController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Item;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class ItemController extends Controller
{

public function index(){
    $items = item::all();
    return view('admin.items',['items' => $items]);
}

public function destroy($itemNo){
    item::destroy($itemNo);
    return redirect('/admin/items');
}

public function newItem(){
    return view('admin.new');
}

public function add() {

    $file = Request::file('file');
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Storage::disk('local')->put($file->getFilename().'.'.$extension,          File::get($file));

    $entry = new \App\File();
    $entry->mime = $file->getClientMimeType();
    $entry->original_filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $entry->filename = $file->getFilename().'.'.$extension;

    $entry->save();

    $Item  = new Item();
    $Item->file_id=$entry->id;
    $Item->itemName =Request::input('name');
    $Item->itemDescription =Request::input('description');
    $Item->price =Request::input('price');
    $Item->imageurl =Request::input('imageurl');

    $Item->save();

    return redirect('admin/items');

}
}
```

Comment: When are you getting the error?

Comment: when i want to cast route '/cart';

Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Not able to figure what you are trying to achieve. In which function or line are you getting the error ? What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: Can you post the route so we can see what it is calling?

Comment: im not suspecting any problem to the route. if there is there would be route error

    //cart
   Route::get('/additem/{ItemId}', 'CartController@addItem');
   Route::get('/removeitem/{ItemId}', 'CartController@removeItem');
   Route::get('/cart', 'CartController@showCart');